# libgdx, moving a list of sprites horizontally

Tags: java, libgdx

in my game, I am trying to make a list of sprites move horizontally. Here is my render method:

```
public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        int speed = 3;
        ConveyorBelt cnb = new ConveyorBelt();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Sprite s = new Sprite(img);
            s.setPosition(500 - 100 * i, 100);
            cnb.belt.push(s);
        }
        batch.begin();
        for (Sprite s : cnb.belt) {
            s.draw(batch);
            s.setX(s.getX() + speed);
        }
        batch.end();
    }
```

I want one of the sprites from the list to disappear, once hitting a certain point on the screen. Unfortunately, they dont seem to move. What is the reason fot that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a brand new list of sprites every time `render()` is called. They all start at the initial positions you gave them, regardless of what you did to the sprites from the previous frame that are now all gone.

Move your `new ConveyorBelt()` and Sprite creation loop into `create()`.